Show whole row if there is a value in one of a number of specific columns
I have a spreadsheet that acts as a simple project plan.  Each line refers to a particular workstream of the project.  Each workstream has several people associated with it.  I am trying to work out how to filter by person.  For example, if Rodney Rodnerson is associated with workstream 2,7, 24 and 89, I would like to select his name from a drop down of all people and have the sheet show only those lines.  There are over 100 people overall within the workstreams so being able to see each individual like this would be invaluable in scheduling their actions.
EDITED:


Sorry that wasn't clear. I have columns headed with people's names. If a person is involved in a project, that line in their column has an "x" in it. If they are not, it is blank.
I would like to filter the specific column that matches the name in a drop down. Lets say Dave is Column BD and he involved in projects 7,12,and 55. I want to select Dave's name from a drop down so that it filters his column and only shows the rows marked x.
However, if I then change the drop down to Sue (who is column BY) I would like it to unfilter on column BD ()Dave) and filter instead on BY (Sue)


Seems like you need a FILTER() function. Could you show us what you have tried ? As well a short sample to mimic your actuals to show what you have and what you need this not only helps you to arrive at a proper solution but also helps others to provide few other alternatives.

Sorry that wasn't clear.  I have columns headed with people's names.  If a person is involved in a project, that line in their column has an "x" in it.  If they are not, it is blank.  I would like to filter the specific column that matches the name in a drop down.  Lets say Dave is Column BD and he involved in projects 7,12,and 55.  I want to select Dave's name from a drop down so that it filters his column and only shows the rows marked x.  However, ifIi then change the drop down to Sue (who is column BY) I would like it to unfilter on column BD ()Dave) and filter instead on BY (Sue).

Hi Steve, i have posted an answer as per your comments, please review and let me know, if any changes you would like to make if required.

Also I have posted your comment in the OP/Original Post so that it reflects others to know what you were looking for. But for record next time, please edit your post and write it down there, it helps! Thanks!

Hereby an example of the Filter() function: my worksheet contains four cells B2-B4, containing "a,b,c", "b,c,d" and "c,d,e". Using the following Filter() worksheet function, I can make sure I only see entries, containing "b":
=FILTER(B2:B4;ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b";B2:B4)))

Explanatory screenshot:


So, if I have understood correctly, from the comments posted by OP, then the following formula should work here:
Per OPs Comment:

Sorry that wasn't clear. I have columns headed with people's names. If
a person is involved in a project, that line in their column has an
"x" in it. If they are not, it is blank. I would like to filter the
specific column that matches the name in a drop down. Lets say Dave is
Column BD and he involved in projects 7,12,and 55. I want to select
Dave's name from a drop down so that it filters his column and only
shows the rows marked x. However, ifIi then change the drop down to
Sue (who is column BY) I would like it to unfilter on column BD
()Dave) and filter instead on BY (Sue). – Steve Doore




• Formula used in cell BD12
=FILTER(FILTER(BD2:BY9,BD1:BY1=BC12),BC2:BC9="x")


One another alternative:
=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(BD2:BY9,BC2:BC9="x"),XMATCH(BC12,BD1:BY1))



Thank you - the above is nearly what I'm looking at.  In Dave and Sue's columns there is two possible values - "x" or "blank".  There are another 90 columns with names.  I want to see only the rows that has an x in Dave's column,.   Then I want to switch to see only rows that have an x in Sue's column.  Then I'd like to see rows only with an x in Raj's column etc etc.  If I could pick the column to look at from a drop down list of the names that would be perfect!  Thank you so much for trying!

@SteveDoore Sir, is it not returning what you are asking for. Can you please if you dont mind post some short sample with three/four columns and the expected output it will help me clearly understand. Because visualization helps more i think. The above formula is intended dynamic if you change the dropdowns it will work, only you need to change cell reference and ranges accordingly as per your data.
